# How to deploy to local tomcat with gradle-cargo-plugin?

Tags: tomcat, deployment, war, gradle, cargo

I want to deploy multiple different war dependencies to a local installation of tomcat in the build directory.
I found the

```
bmuschko:gradle-cargo-plugin:0.3
```

but have no idea to deploy the war file.
The plugin provides the task cargoStartLocal but unfortunately the documentation (see https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-cargo-plugin) of this plugin tells nothing about how to deploy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With version 0.3 it is not possible to define an arbitrary WAR file to be deployed to a local container. It only uses the artifact of the build script that you apply the plugin to. Currently I am working on a new version of the plugin that will let you define a specific deployable (WAR or EAR file) within its configuration closure. You can expect a new version of the plugin within the next 2 weeks.

Can you tell me a little bit more about your use case so I can potentially account for it in my plugin code? If I read this correctly you want to deploy multiple WAR files from one specific build script?

FYI: I'd prefer feature requests and questions via a GitHub issue or email directly. I only found this question by chance. Usually you'll get a faster feedback by directly contacting the developers that wrote the code. I'd be happy to help you with setting up your project and extend my plugin for specific use cases.

Comment: I just released version 0.4 which support this feature.